# Advice on how to find multiple strings in a log while being written?

Tags: c#, string, search, logging, text

I need to read from a log file as it is being written and search (and copy) certain strings. For example, when a test starts there is a string in the log file that says "test is starting" followed by a number of important strings for me to copy like "name of the unit: ...", "unit's number.." and so on.

Shortly before the test ends there are another few strings that i need to copy followed by a "test ends" string.

I need to read this info "on the fly" (while the log is being written). Those log files can get quite big.

How do you advise me to do that with C#? Is there a simple way I should consider?

Comment: How is the file being written?

Comment: @phoog, the file is being written through another software that is continuously testing and reporting its results.

Comment: What if you would try to use memory stream and afterwards filter out data of your liking?

Comment: It's hard to interpret the requirements/limitations. But sounds like an approach to consider would be remembering where you last read in the log file after each read. On each subsequent read, scan to where you last left off and then start reading until end of file again. If you need to load it all in memory beforehand to avoid concurrency issues, then it is what it is.

Comment: If the other software has an exclusive lock on the file then you might have some problems.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do this in C#, as there are tools out there, including many open source tools, that handle real time log monitoring. None are 100% real time, but you can get pretty damned close. You have them write the log information where it can be used by your code, if needed. Reinventing this wheel is very time consuming. I have not searched, but it is possible there is a C# real time log monitor that is open source, so it is worth a search. You could then incorporate the code in your application.

If you MUST do this in C#, you would "watch" the log to indicate when a change has been made. You then have to read through. And that could be expensive. But, you can save the file size from the last read and then use seek to get to the tail much quicker than reading line by line.

The only other way I can think of is to intercept the writing of the log by creating a "proxy" between the program and the file. I would have to research the best way to do this, but you would essentially be capturing the bytes as they were written. You would need pretty firm understanding of what was being written so you could terminate each line just in case quite a few lines are written at one time. Likely you would end up PInvoking to use native windows libraries to create this interception of the messages as they were written.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how if you control how the file is being written. One way to do it is to set `FileShare.ReadWrite`

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(
      @"c:\words.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, 
      FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite );
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks. My problem is not to access the file but to seek my string continuously while being written and save relevant data

Comment: Ahh, icic. You most likely just want a stream that keeps seeking the end of the file in a loop.